# SqlDateTime overflow thrown by Typed DataSet Insert

Tags: strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using a Typed DataSet with an Insert statement; I have a table that has a smalldatetime field defined to accept null values.  When I insert from a .NET 2.0 FormView, I get a "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

Now, I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-9999), and the parameter as sent to the class constructor is defined as

```
global::System.Nullable<global::System.DateTime> DoB
```

So, it looks like it should accept a Nullable obj.  Additionally, the generated code is testing the value sent.

```
        if ((DoB.HasValue == true)) {
            command.Parameters[6].Value = ((System.DateTime)(DoB.Value));
        }
        else {
            command.Parameters[6].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
        }
```

Specifically, the error is occurring when generated SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() runs:

```
        try {
            returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

So, I guess my question is: how do I use a Typed DataSet to set a blank value (passed from a FormView on CommandName=Insert) to a null in a database?

Comment: Additional followup:  Part of the problem here is I can't debug this.  As a work-around, I copied the object and made my own. Since typed datasets create partial classes for their tableadapters, I tapped into it and added a duplicate of the Insert object.  That allowed me to put a breakpoint on it and see what the values is.

Part II: If you look at the FormViewInsertEventArgs, the date is being sent as null.  However, when you compare it to the Insert method, you'll find that's changed to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}... More work needed...

Comment: Ok, there has to be a bug in the way MS has implemented their reflection routines.  If I change the parameter type in my method to string, it comes over as a blank.  If I evaluate Nullable<DateTime> nix = ""; I *do* get a null.  There *must* be something wrong in ObjectDataSourceMethod GetResolvedMethodData() call since it's creating a list of parameters to invoke the method with.  Somewhere, I think it's just doing a new DateTime(), not a new Nullable<DateTime>(). I just don't have more time to look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what worked for me.  First, to reiterate, I've got a Typed DataSet with DataAdapters that's generating the ADO objects. So, on my page, I can create a ObjectDataSource with the type that points to my adapter, and then name the different access methods housed there-in.

No, I have an Insert to a table where basically all the columns are nullable; some varchar, some smalldatetime.

When I submit an empty form, I'd like nulls to be entered.  They're not and lots of various errors are thrown.  What I ended up doing is subclassing the ObjectDataSource to gain access to the Inserting event. (subclassed for reusability)  In the Inserting event, I looped through the InputParameters, and if it was a string and == "", I set it to null.  Also, you cannot set ConvertNullToDBNull to true; that causes the strings to fail.  This successfully allowed the Nullable to remain null.