# SqlDateTime overflow Exception in Select command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exception, stored-procedures

I use stored procedure to get paged list and this is my method:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[GetPagedSP]", conn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       //Passing Parameters 
       **Update**
       SqlParameter spCreationDate = new SqlParameter("@CreationDate_9", CreationDate);
       spCreationDate.IsNullable = true;
       cmd.Parameters.Add(spCreationDate);

       // ........
       //Finished Passing Parameters
       conn.Open();

       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while(dr.Read()) {
          //Get Values
       }
       conn.Close();
   }
}
```

And this is my stored procedure command:

```
CREATE TABLE #PagingTemp  (
[RowId]           [bigint]    IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL,
[RecordId]        [bigint]  
);

INSERT INTO [#PagingTemp] ([RecordId])
SELECT  [CAR].[Id]      
FROM [Article] AS [CAR] ;

SELECT [CAR].*
FROM [Collections].[Article] AS [CAR]
INNER JOIN [#PagingTemp] AS [PT] ON [CAR].[Id] = [PT].[RecordId]
WHERE [PT].[RowId] BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```

When I run the query in SQL every thing is fine, But in .NET I have an exception on this line:

`SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

and the exception is:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
>   Source=System.Data

**Update**

The example of run Query in SQL:
[image]

That's so weird I don't understand what happened?

I don't have any `datetime` value that be bigger than `12/31/9999` or less than `1/1/1753`

I just have some Nullable datetime values with null value in database.

what do you think? where is the problem?

Comment: Check that your date/time column is returning a value and not null, otherwise you need to set your DateTime to DateTime?.

Comment: @Gavin As I said I have some `nullable` columns that returns null, but in object side my types are `DateTime?`, also before any mapping an exception throw in this line: `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Out of interest, if you do have any DateTime values, can you post an example of one?

Comment: ah... Just out of interest, are you passing any date/time objects as parameters into your query? i.e. before con.Open(); If so, debug and make sure the date is not null, and is between the above dates

Comment: @Gavin Yes, I pass a  nullable datetime parameter but the value of that is also null, I update the question see pass parameters part, Is this any fault to pass null value fore nullable datetime?

Comment: `CreationDate` is probably zero, not null but zero. Could you please verify that?

Comment: I think the issue is, your query is trying to parse that null variable into a datetime type. I don't think SQL has the ability to handle that, so you would need to check if it is null or not first. i.e. `select * from Car where (Car.Date is null or Car.Date = @Variable)`

Comment: @Gavin I don't think so, I pass a where clause string parameter, The datetime parameter which I passed, just used if in where clause mention that. but the value of where clause is empty string.

Comment: @Gavin I just checked again, your right the passed date time parameter wasn't null, I'm sorry, and Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  `Gavin` And `Nikola Markovinović` mentioned in comments in select command when you passed the `DateTime` type parameter need to check the parameter value is in correct range or not (`1/1/1753 to 12/31/9999`)? I pass a `Nullable DateTime` parameter and I thought the value of that is null, also I never use this parameter in  the query in this case, so the null value is correct and the use of parameter in command is not important, when I check again I found that the value of parameter is not null and is `1/1/0001`. another solution is use `DATATIME2` type in `SQL` that support all range of `DateTime` which .Net supports.

Answer (score 0):

Assign any valid date to the variable CreationDate before passing it to execute the stored procedure

```
  //Passing Parameters 

   CreationDate = DateTime.Now or any other date you want if you dont want to pass any date then assign DBNull.Value

   **Update**
   SqlParameter spCreationDate = new SqlParameter("@CreationDate_9", CreationDate);
   spCreationDate.IsNullable = true;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(spCreationDate);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

IF possible, paste the SP here, it would be better to propose a fix. For now, you may consider following possibilities to try to fix it:

If select is causing issue then consider replacing NULL date with min date as following:

```
SELECT IsNULL(CreationDate,'1/1/1753') CreationDate, IsNULL(LastBidDate,'1/1/1753') LastBidDate from yourtable.
```

For reference, here is another answered question:
[error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999)