# SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: c#

I can't seem to find the right answer in other questions like this.

I'm using this piece of code to assign the date that should be saved in the database.

```
request.BranchRequestDate = DateTime.Now;
```

And when I'm trying to retrieve the data from the table using this function.

```
public Request SelectByID()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = this.GetParametizedCommand("SELECT * FROM Request WHERE RequestUID = '" + this.RequestUID.ToString() + "' ;");
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(tbl); //This is where the exception is thrown
            return ToEntity(tbl);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

...It throws and exception.

I've tried checking everything, but what I can't figure out is why it throws and exception, as I can't see what the retrieved data looks like in C#, but I've tried the statement in SQL Server itself and it returns the correct data.

Any idea?

EDIT: I have also compared it with a similar function in the same program, and it functions just fine.

EDIT:
Code for GetParametizedCommand method

```
public SqlCommand GetParametizedCommand(String commandText)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = base.GetSqlCommand(commandText);
            if(SavingStatus == Util.SavingStatus.INSERT)
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestUID", SqlDbType.Int,32, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 38, 38, "RequestUID", DataRowVersion.Default, this.RequestUID));
            else if (SavingStatus == Util.SavingStatus.UPDATE || SavingStatus == Util.SavingStatus.DELETE)
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestUID", SqlDbType.Int,32, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 38, 38, "RequestUID", DataRowVersion.Default, this.RequestUID));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayID", this.DisplayID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchUID", this.BranchUID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeUID", this.EmployeeUID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchRequestDate", this.BranchRequestDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", this.IsDeleted);
            return command;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: well... do you have any values in your database that could cause this?

Comment: What does GetParametizedCommand do?

Comment: @RandomUs1r, what do you mean? The only date field in that table is the BranchRequestDate.

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: @MichaelLiu, it just adds parameters to the SQL command for inserting, updating, and deleting. But if the statement is just a SELECT statement, it just adds the parameters but does nothing with them.

Comment: @A.Still, SQLTypeException

Comment: I think you should show the code for GetParametizedCommand.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, edited original post.

Comment: I see its been answered, but you can also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception might be happening because `this.BranchRequestDate` hasn't been initialized when you call `GetParametizedCommand` with the SELECT statement.

Because `this.BranchRequestDate` hasn't been initialized, it equals `DateTime.MinValue`, which isn't a valid SQL datetime value.

You could add an explicit check for `DateTime.MinValue` and avoid adding the parameter in that situation:

```
if (this.BranchRequestDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchRequestDate", this.BranchRequestDate);
```

Or you might create a `GetCommand` method that doesn't add any parameters at all for a SELECT statement.

Comment: Where [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) appears to be January 1, 0001, well before the (Gregorian calendar) start date of January 1, 1753 for [SqlDateTime.MinValue Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx)