# Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working updating customer details in gridview. Here, I am using 3 tier architecture. I am trying to update certain fields. But, I end up getting above mentioned error. 
Here is my code.

```
protected void MyProfileGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);

        TextBox name = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Name");
        TextBox shopName = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_ShopName");
        TextBox address = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Address");
        TextBox mobile1 = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Mobile1");
        TextBox mobile2 = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Mobile2");
        TextBox password = (TextBox)MyProfileGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_Password");

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.CustomerID = customerId;
        customer.CustomerName = name.Text;
        customer.ShopName = shopName.Text;
        customer.Address = address.Text;
        customer.Mobile1 = mobile1.Text;
        customer.Mobile2 = mobile2.Text;
        customer.Password = password.Text;

        CustomerBL.UpdateCustomer(customer);
        MyProfileGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        MyProfileGridView.DataSource = CategoryBL.GetCategories();
        MyProfileGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Business Logic Layer code for updating customer.

```
public static void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [Customers] SET [LoginID] = @LoginID, [Password] = @Password, [CustomerName] = @CustomerName, [ShopName] = @ShopName, [Address] = @Address, [Mobile1] = @Mobile1, [Mobile2] = @Mobile2, [ReferenceNumber] = @ReferenceNumber, [SignUpDate] = @SignUpDate, [Enabled] = @Enabled WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.LoginID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Password;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.CustomerName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShopName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.ShopName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Address;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Mobile1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Mobile2;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNumber", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.ReferenceNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignUpDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = customer.SignUpDate;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enabled", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = customer.Enabled;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.CustomerID;

        DbUtility.UpdateDb(cmd);
    }
```

Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is value of `customer.SignUpDate` ?

Comment: Where did you set SignUpDate?
It seems you forgot set DateTime for that field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999)

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. And since the only DateTime in your code is `customer.SignUpDate`, there is probably a conversion problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SignUpDate` is not being populated, therefore `DateTime.MinValue` is being used, which is not valid for `SqlDbType.DateTime`
However.. the somewhat confusing part to me is that you specify `SqlDbType.DateTime2` when adding your parameters.
I suspect when you created your table, you in fact use `SqlDbType.DateTime`

Anyhow, you'll need to populate the date, something like

```
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.SignUpDate = DateTime.Now; //notice this line
    customer.CustomerID = customerId;
    customer.CustomerName = name.Text;
    //etc...
```

Comment: It should be valid for `DateTime2` though.  It's range is 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.  It's not valid for `DateTime`

Comment: true-  this means the error the OP is receiving suggests that although he specified `DateTime2` it's not actually using it - the out of range error suggests it's using `DateTime` - weird

Comment: Agreed.  Your answer however states _DateTime.MinValue is being used, which is **not valid** for SqlDbType.DateTime2_.  I was just pointing out that it _is_ valid for `DateTime2`

Comment: amended the answer