# Get DateTime from SQL server and assign it to property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following class:

```
public class Invoice
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public DateTime creationDate {get; set;}
}
```

I have invoices saved in my SQL-Server DB with the following properties:

```
invoice
 - invoiceID [int, null] 
 - creationDate [datetime, null]
```

My dates contain the following format: `2018-07-31 00:00:00.000`

However, when I get an invoice with the following

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT id, creationDate FROM invoice WHERE invoiceID = @invoiceID", conn);
        command.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = InvoiceID;
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                temp.ID = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
                temp.InvoiceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["creationDate"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

However, when i run my code, I get the error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line throws that exception? I am 90% sure it isn't coming from the above code. That error is _usually_ related to trying to convert a date to a `SqlDateTime` (which your code isn't doing).

Comment: And what is the value in the database field for the invoice you are trying to read?

Comment: You have a misunderstanding about how SQL datetime values work. Datetimes in SQL have a binary format that is not human readable. You only see yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff because the query tool translates it for you. ADO.Net will do the same. You already have a DateTime value. No need to convert and especially don't call ToString()

Comment: @mjwills the command ´command.ExecuteReader()´ ,

Comment: Please update your post with a screenshot of the exception occurring, and the code behind it showing the current line being executed. Sorry to be a pain, but that exception does some unlikely to be coming from that line so I am keen to see if I am missing something.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the `InvoiceID` variable to something.  Also, why are you defaulting the datetime field of your record to null?  You certainly wouldn't create an invoice record with a null datetime field.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999#468096

Comment: If you can't find a solution, you need to post more code.  Not just snippets and interpretations.

Comment: A few things, unrelated to the issue you are seeing.  Since your SQL fields are nullable, (not sure why CreateDate is nullable, but...), you should make the backing class contain an "int?" and a "DateTime?".  You say "My dates contain the following format: 2018-07-31 00:00:00.000".  Dates don't contain "formats", they contain DateTime entities.  The code you show will not compile: your backing class has ID as an int, and your createDate is a DateTime.  Your code converts everything to strings and assigns them.  Show us code that compiles (like @joelcoehoorn 's code below)

Comment: That exception message is thrown when you try to WRITE a C# datetime (possibly uninitialized) to your database field and not when you try to read it back. I really fail to see how ExecuteReader could throw that exception.

Comment: @mjwills , not  yet as i'm not understanding why i need to 'prove' i have the error thrown in my program...

Comment: Because a number of people here, including myself, believe that error is literally not possible to occur where you say it is occurring. A screenshot will quickly prove me to be incorrect, and we can get on to solving your issue.

Comment: @mjwills , thanks for the reminder, from the moment i will have this code on hands again, i will post a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sane database schema, the `createDate` column is **already** a DateTime value. Converting a string only shoots yourself in the foot. Same for `id` and `int`.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var command = new new SqlCommand(@"SELECT id, creationDate FROM invoice WHERE invoiceID = @invoiceID", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = InvoiceID;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        temp.ID = (int)reader["id"];
        temp.InvoiceDate = (DateTime)reader["creationDate"];
    }
}
```

You do need to be a little more careful if `creationDate` can be `NULL`, but otherwise that simple cast is enough.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  His exception is occurring with his SQL execution, not with his C# code.  In fairness, we're not getting the whole picture (SQL or C#) so it's hard to help anyway.